# Commutative ring which is essential extension of each of its non-zero ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Assume $R$ is an essential extension of each of its non-zero ideals. I feel that there should be something in the literature about this, but I could not find anything. If anyone can provide relevant references, I would be grateful.

I know about essential extensions, but was wondering if something more can be said about the particular situation stated above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module in which every submodule is an essential submodule is called a *uniform module*.  A ring $R$ for which $R_R$ is a uniform module is called a *right uniform ring*.

They were notably used in A. W. Goldie's theory of uniform dimension.

You can find in Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* a chapter devoted to this.